# Can Remote Desktop Gateway be run from a standalone server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, gateway

I have a standalone (non-domain) Windows Server 2008 R2 that I need to securely access using RDP from the public internet. I want to access it using the standard 443 SSL port, since other ports are most likely blocked within corporations and schools etc.
So I read about the Remote Desktop Gateway (former known as the Terminal Services Gateway).
All the examples I have stumbled upon relies on a dedicated server for this role, gatewaying the traffic to the request server within the intranet.

So, can I install the Remote Desktop Gateway role to this standalone server without any issues?
Essentially, it will then acting a a gateway for itself.
I am planning on registering a dedicated host name, such as rd.domain.com (this would also be used to purchase a SSL certificate) that the gateway will use. On the RD client, this would be the gateway name, and the actual remote server name would be the computer name of the server

Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the overwhelming number of answers, I bit the bullet and tried it...
So far it seems to work.
So, yes, it seems that one can run the RD gateway role on a single server instance, RD'ing to itself.

Comment: could you please post the configuration settings here? Especially RD CAP and RAP. Im trying to achieve the same thing as you did, installing RD Gateway on the same server i want to RDP to.
Many thanks

Comment: Dude, this post is over 11 years old. Do you think I have the configuration settings laying around? The short answer do that is .. no. Sorry.